# Implement hreflang with multi sites

Tags: localization, multi-site, craft2, plugin-seomatic

I currently have multi site config. One site have 2 locales.
My configuration like so:

```
'example.com' => array(
    'siteUrl' => array(
        'us_en' => 'https://www.example.com/',
        'br_sp' => 'https://www.example.com/sp'
    ),
'example.uk' => array(
    'siteUrl' => array(
        'uk_en' => 'https://www.example.uk/',
    ).
```

I'm using SEOmatic plugin.
Hreflang requires all site have to list on the head of page.
However, SEO list 2 locales which are us_en and br_sp on a site only.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to ensure that all of the sites that are a translation of each other are in the same site group, as detailed here: [SEOmatic Multi-Site Language/Locale Support](https://nystudio107.com/docs/seomatic/Technologies.html#multi-site-language-locale-support)

Comment: Dose this one support for craft 2?

Comment: Ah apologies, no -- it's for Craft 3 only.